# Why do I get expected parameter error when using a Stored Procedure to create rows through a Trigger on a View?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

There are three tables in database:

1. "BusinessEntity". 2. "Firm" and, 3. "Customer". Their relationship is shown in the picture.
   [image: Table relationship]

Whenever a new Customer row is to be created:

1. A new BusinessEntity row should be created automatically
2. It should pass its BusinessEntityID value to an (automatically) newly created Firm row.
3. Finally the newly created Firm should its own BusinessEntityID to Customer table as FirmID column.

(A Firm cannot be created without first creating a BusinessEntity row, in a 1-to-1 relationship and a new Customer should either be a new Firm or Person)

I've created this stored procedure to automatically create a new Customer by inserting a new pair of BusinessEntity and Firm rows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateFirmCustomer](@FirmName NVARCHAR(30), @CustomerName NVARCHAR(28)) AS 
BEGIN;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT BusinessEntity DEFAULT VALUES;
DECLARE @BusinessEntityID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Firm] ON

INSERT Firm(BusinessEntityID, FirmName)
VALUES (@BusinessEntityID, @FirmName);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Firm] OFF

INSERT Customer(FirmID, CustomerName)
VALUES (@BusinessEntityID, @CustomerName);
DECLARE @CustomerID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

SELECT @BusinessEntityID AS FirmID, @CustomerID AS CustomerID;

COMMIT;
END;

GO
```

Then I created this view to insert Customers as Firms by use of an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vBusEntityFirmCustomer]
AS
SELECT dbo.Firm.FirmName, dbo.Customer.CustomerName
FROM dbo.BusinessEntity INNER JOIN
     dbo.Firm ON dbo.BusinessEntity.BusinessEntityID = dbo.Firm.BusinessEntityID INNER JOIN
     dbo.Customer ON dbo.Firm.BusinessEntityID = dbo.Customer.FirmID
GO
```

And this trigger on the view:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_FirmCustomer]
ON [dbo].[vBusEntityFirmCustomer]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
   exec [dbo].[CreateFirmCustomer]
GO
```

But every time I enter a new FirmName CustomerName to insert a new row I get this message (see image):

Procedure or function 'CreateFirmCustomer' expects parameter '@FirmName', which was not supplied.
The fact is that I do supply FirmName (as well as CustomerName) through the view.

[image: Error]

What's wrong?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear...you didn't provide @FirmName when calling CreateFirmCustomer. I would ask why do you need that to be two tables? They have a 1:1 relationship. Just merge that into a single table and be done with it.

Comment: @sean As I mentioned I do provide both FirmName and CustomerName through the view. So what's to be changed? Now the two table 1:1 schema is needed for other purposes...

Comment: No, you're calling "Exec dbo.CreateFirmCustomer", and that is defined as taking a parameter... which you're not passing.

Comment: Further, if anyone were to insert multiple rows at once, this would fail because you're not passing the INSERTED collection or anything... there's just a lot wrong with this entire approach here.

Comment: Look again. See there in your trigger? "exec [dbo].[CreateFirmCustomer]" You are NOT passing FirmName OR CustomerName to that procedure. This is the current issue, but there are other issues here as well like pmbAustin mentioned.

Comment: I can't possibly imagine why a 1:1 relationship between tables is required. Unless this is part of a third party application or something that you are extending this wouldn't server any benefit.

Comment: I see. So how should the trigger look like?

Comment: @sean Any suggestions?

Comment: @pmbAustin Any suggestions?

Comment: Step back and re-think the entire thing, because this approach is just all kinds of wrong and will never work for you. As stated above, if BusinessEntity and Firm are 1:1, why have them in separate tables? But more to the point, just put triggers on the appropriate tables (AFTER INSERT), and use the inserted collection to update the child table. Eliminate the stored procedure entirely... that's totally the wrong approach.

Comment: I agree that a rethinking is the logical approach here. You were asking about the trigger. Look at the code inside of it, it is not passing the required parameters to your procedure. As such, it will never work like that. You would have to use a loop to call that for every row in the inserted table. When you start seeing loops in a trigger you know that something is horribly wrong.

Comment: Thank you both sean and austin.